# free memory after using HMAC() function?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

I have the following function:

```
static int my_hmac(unsigned char *data, int len, char *password, unsigned char *hmac)
{
    unsigned char* digest;

    digest = HMAC(EVP_sha1(), password, strlen(password), data, len, NULL, NULL);
    memcpy(hmac, digest, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

I call it in the `main()` in this way

```
unsigned char buffer[20]
my_hmac(str, strlen(str), "password", buffer)
```

Should I call some free memory api of libcrypto/libopenssl after using the `HMAC()` function ?

Comment: It looks like the area `digest` points to has been allocated by the `HMAC` function, so I'd say yes

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca 
 
I tried with valgrind and there is no memory leak!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested with valgrind, there is no memory leak after using `HMAC()`

**DEMO**

*test.c:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

static int my_hmac(unsigned char *data, int len, char *password, unsigned char *hmac)
{
    unsigned char* digest;
    digest = HMAC(EVP_sha1(), password, strlen(password), data, len, NULL, NULL);
    memcpy(hmac, digest, 20);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char buf[20];
    char *txt = "kallel";   
    my_hmac(txt, strlen(txt), "password", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

*build and run with valgrind:*

```
mylinux ~ $ gcc -o test test.c -lcrypto
mylinux ~ $ valgrind ./test
==5447== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5447== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5447== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5447== Command: ./test
==5447== 
==5447== 
==5447== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5447==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5447==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 312 bytes allocated
==5447== 
==5447== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5447== 
==5447== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5447== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your post `openssl`, I'll assume you're using that.

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Hmac(3)), since you passed `NULL` as the argument for `md` (second last argument), the result is placed in a static array, so no need for you to worry about deallocation there.

As for the return value,

> `HMAC()` returns a pointer to the message authentication code or `NULL` if an error occurred.

This message authentication code is not memory owned by you, and therefore you should not try to free it.

Comment: @MOHAMED: Did you expect one?

Comment: not really, but I find example on the net that are usin HMAC() without any free then I thought that the HMAC() is using some static buffer as returned pointer